# Thread in my code does not work

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep

Here is the code, Results Activity should start if button is clicked:

```
 public class Tab19 extends Activity {

ImageButton button1;
SoundPool mSoundPool;
AssetManager assets;
int catSound;
int countLoadedSound;
Context mContext;
ProgressDialog dialog;
int count = 0;
TextView t;
boolean has_been_clicked = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab19);


    count = getIntent().getIntExtra("CountNum", 0); 
    mContext = this;        
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    assets = getAssets();       
    catSound = loadSound("catSound.mp3");

    button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            playSound(catSound);
            Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Tab19.this, Results.class);
            TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
            t.setText("score: " + ++count +"/18");
            firstIntent.putExtra("CountNum", count);
            has_been_clicked = true;
            startActivity(firstIntent);                 
            finish();
        }
    }); 

    new Thread(
              new Runnable() { 
                public void run() { 
                  while (!has_been_clicked) {

                      try {
                            // Thread will sleep for 10 seconds
                            sleep(10*1000);

                      } catch (Exception e) {

                        }

                  }
                  Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Results.class);
                    i.putExtra("CountNum", count);
                  startActivity(i);
                  finish();
                  return;

                }

                private void sleep(int i) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
              }
            ).start();   }  

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy(); }

        protected void playSound(int sound) {
            if (sound > 0)
                mSoundPool.play(sound, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        }

        private int loadSound(String fileName) {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
            try {
                afd = assets.openFd(fileName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Не могу загрузить файл " + fileName,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return -1;
            }

            return mSoundPool.load(afd, 1);

} }
```

If button is not clicked Thread should start next Activity within 10 seconds, but it does  not happen, please help me find a mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: Put a `Log.d()` object just after the `while` loop, and see in logcat if it gets fired or not.

Comment: Why do you have your own local implementation of sleep() which does nothing?  Also, since you did not declare your flag as `volatile` your thread may not actually check to see if it has been updated from another thread, nor for that matter is the other thread obligated to actually commit an update to memory.

Comment: The way of implementing this is correct, but is there any reason why you just don't implement that within the `onClick()` listener? This way the user clicks on the image, the activity `finish()`es and starts the another without delay.

Comment: @nKn the idea is that user should find a button and click it(it is not conspicuous), if user doesn't do that,then another activity start and score does not inсrease

Comment: Then you should use the `Log.d()` idea and see where the trouble is.

Answer (score 0):

Into your thread change the while loop into an if statement:

```
 if (!has_been_clicked) {
     try {
          // Thread will sleep for 10 seconds
          sleep(10*1000);
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your code to

```
              boolean has_been_clicked = true;
              ...
              while (has_been_clicked) {
                  has_been_clicked = false;
                  try {
                        // Thread will sleep for 10 seconds
                        sleep(10*1000);

                  } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
              }
              Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Results.class);
                i.putExtra("CountNum", count);
              startActivity(i);
              finish();
              return;
```